# How to get 3200 tweets from a new Twitter's API and what is GetOldTweets3 alternative?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, python-twitter

As it is clear `GetOldTweets3` is a python library for accessing old tweets which is not easily feasible with libraries like `Tweepy`. But recently, there is an unsolved issue with it due to the new Twitter API: https://github.com/Mottl/GetOldTweets3/issues/98.

The question is what is `GetOldTweets3` alternative library for retrieving tweets without time constraints? In my experience, `Tweepy` can not retrieve more than 200 tweets.

Answer (score 1):

So far the only method of scraping tweets that still seems to work is snscrape's jsonl method.
or this
https://github.com/rsafa/get-latest-tweets/

Answer (score 0):

The 200 tweet limit is a per request maximum. You can retrieve successive "pages" of tweets by using the returned `next` parameter to request the next page of 200. If you are using the Standard Search API, these requests will stop return tweets older than about a week. With Premium Search API full-archive you can get all tweets going back to 2006.

It is explained in detail here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference

Comment: Can you please tell me how exactly can I retrieve more than 200 tweets with Tweepy?
`def text_query_to_csv(text_query, count):
    try:
        for tweet in api.search(q=text_query, count=count):
            # Adding to list that contains all tweets
            tweets.append((tweet.created_at, tweet.user.screen_name, tweet.text, tweet.entities))

            tweetsdf = pd.DataFrame(tweets, columns=['Datetime', 'Screen Name', 'Text', 'Entities'])
            tweetsdf.to_csv('{}-tweets.csv'.format(text_query))

Comment: I don't use Tweepy, but I can give you an example using [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI). https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI/blob/master/examples/page_tweets.py

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using snscrape. The IDs collected in this way can then be pass to api.statuses_lookup. By using api.statuses_lookup you can download 300*100 tweets per 15 minutes via Twitter api.

```
# you have a list with all Tweets ids created with snscrape: all_id_list
# split list in a list of list with 100 ids

id_list = [all_id_list[x:x+100] for x in range(0, len(all_id_list), 100)]

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# iterated over the list to get per request 100 tweets over the twitter api
for i in id_list:
     tweets = api.statuses_lookup(list(id_list[i]))

     for tweet in tweets:
          print(tweet.text)
```